# Is there a standard set of HTTP 500.xx codes?

Tags: http, rest, web

I've seen servers return 500 Internal Server Error codes with extra 'detail' in a decimal-delimited sub-code, e.g. 500.19.

Is this sub-code standardised or can I freely use it? How do I prevent crashing into vendor codes, say, in IIS or ASP.NET?

Luke

Comment: I don't get this counter, I have 7 questions of 50 unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *Microsoft* standard list. See - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891

> IIS 7.0 defines the following HTTP status codes that indicate a more specific cause of a 500 error:
>
> - 500.0 - Module or ISAPI error occurred.
>
>   - 500.11 - Application is shutting down on the web server.
>   - 500.12 - Application is busy restarting on the web server.
>   - 500.13 - Web server is too busy.
>   - 500.15 - Direct requests for Global.asax are not allowed.
>   - 500.19 - Configuration data is invalid.
>   - 500.21 - Module not recognized.
>   - 500.22 - An ASP.NET httpModules configuration does not apply in Managed Pipeline mode.
>   - 500.23 - An ASP.NET httpHandlers configuration does not apply in Managed Pipeline mode.
>   - 500.24 - An ASP.NET impersonation configuration does not apply in Managed Pipeline mode.
>   - 500.50 - A rewrite error occurred during RQ_BEGIN_REQUEST notification handling. A configuration or inbound rule execution error occurred.
>   - Note Here is where the distributed rules configuration is read for both inbound and outbound rules.
>   - 500.51 - A rewrite error occurred during GL_PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST notification handling. A global configuration or global rule execution error occurred.
>   - Note Here is where the global rules configuration is read.
>   - 500.52 - A rewrite error occurred during RQ_SEND_RESPONSE notification handling. An outbound rule execution occurred.
>   - 500.53 - A rewrite error occurred during RQ_RELEASE_REQUEST_STATE notification handling. An outbound rule execution error occurred. The rule is configured to be executed before the output user cache gets updated.
>   - 500.100 - Internal ASP error.

Comment: "What Microsoft does" != "Standard".

Comment: Interesting. So, with CodeCaster's findings and this, I could invent an internal system for our own instrumentation.

Comment: I would not recommend creating something off this.  It is a microsoft standard and may change with the next iteration of IIS.  Better to create something specific to your application.

Comment: I've given most of the points to you since you were first and CodeCaster already has lots :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is this sub-code standardised or can I freely use it?

It is not possible to use it, quote [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1):

> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer

MSDN says for the [`HttpResponse.SubStatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.substatuscode.aspx):

> Independent of whether tracing is configured, **the code is never sent as part of the final response to the request**

So, it is only used for logging and troubleshooting, not sent to the client.

Comment: Well done. I never noticed that property! I wasn't in the IDE when I put the question together, rather, looking at logs.